# Expression for Change in temperature

Tags: arithmetic

**The temperature in Brownsville fell from 25°F to −23°F in 8 minutes.
a. Write a numerical expression you can evaluate to find the average change in temperature per minute.
b. Find the mean change in temperature per minute.**

This question is from my 6th graders Math textbook. Would appreciate a simple explanation that an elementary grade student can comprehend. Thanks in advance!

*Edit: I found the solution elsewhere as -( 25 -(-23)) ÷ 8 . Is this correct?* *If so, please explain why the expression to find the change in temperature is -(25 - (-23)) ?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numerical expression for temperature change from 25°F to −23°F in 8 minutes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3015168/numerical-expression-for-temperature-change-from-25f-to-%e2%88%9223f-in-8-minutes)

Answer (score -1):

That's a strange way of putting it.  It's simply $${-23-25\over8}=-6\text{ degrees per minute}$$  Change in temperature divided by the time interval. 
The answer in the book is correct, but I don't understand the reason for the "double negative."

Comment: There's something fishy about Pearl deliberately posting duplicate questions here (this isn't the only one). Maybe you don't want to have an answer associated with these shenanigans.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I assume it's just because my answer on the previous one wasn't to her liking; specifically because I couldn't adequately answer her question regarding the "how to calculate the change in temperature" thing. Wasn't really able to reply because I don't really know how to phrase or explain "the change in temperature" or "final temp minus initial temp" as anything more elementary/intuitive. >_>